# Asymptotic sequence $\phi_{n,m}(\lambda)$

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

Consider a family of functions $$\phi_{nm}(\lambda) = \lambda^{m} e^{−n \lambda},$$ where the integers $n = 1, 2, 3, \cdot \cdot \cdot, \infty \ $  and  $ \ m =1, 2, 3 , \cdot \cdot \cdot \ ,\ n.$

(a) Prove that the above sequence is an asymptotic sequence as $\lambda \to +\infty,$

(b) Write down the first 6 terms of this asymptotic sequence.

**My Approach**

For $\ m =1, 2, 3 , \cdot \cdot \cdot \ ,\ n, \text{ we have },$

$$\phi_{n1}(\lambda) = \bigg\{ \lambda  e^{−n \lambda} \bigg \}_{ n =1}^{\infty},\ \phi_{n2}(\lambda) = \bigg\{ \lambda^2  e^{−n \lambda} \bigg \}_{ n =1}^{\infty},  \cdot \cdot \cdot,  \phi_{nn}(\lambda) = \bigg\{ \lambda^{n} e^{−n \lambda} \bigg \}_{ n =1}^{\infty}$$

Let $\Phi_{n}(\lambda) :=  \phi_{nn}(\lambda) = \bigg\{ \lambda^{n} e^{−n \lambda} \bigg \}_{ n =1}^{\infty}$

We have $$ \lim _{\lambda \to +\infty} \frac{\Phi_{n+1}(\lambda) }{\Phi_{n}(\lambda) } = \lim _{\lambda \to +\infty} \  \frac{1}{e^{\lambda}} = 0$$

which proves $$ \Phi_{n+1}(\lambda) = \mathcal{}o \bigg(\Phi_{n}(\lambda)\bigg), \text { as } {\lambda \to +\infty}.$$

$\textbf{My question:}$

1. Is this sufficient in order to prove that $\phi_{nm}(\lambda)$ is an asymptotic sequence?
2. If the above methodology is correct then how to re-arrange the terms in order to write the first six terms?